# PHP - Empty SQL result disapear table

Tags: php, sql

I met something strange. When I get an empty SQL result, all `<tr> <td>` disappear. When the SQL result has data, the table and data presentation work correctly. Can you please help to clear this situation?

```
<?php  
  $stidf = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT MIN(creation_time), TO_CHAR 
                             (MIN(creation_time), 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM 
                             table");

  $rf=oci_execute($stidf);

  while ($rowf = oci_fetch_array($stidf, OCI_BOTH)) {   ?>          

<td><?php if ($rowf[0] == NULL) {echo "x";} else { echo $rowf[1];} ?></b></td>
```

Comment: i see a missing `<b>` tag

Comment: there is no mention of <tr> or <td> in your code. could yyou include the part which you expect to generate them?

Comment: Well, because your td are in a while loop, so while there is results, its fine, otherwise there wont be TD, but like someone told you, we cant see TR tag, and btw I think automaticaly if td doesnt exist in TR it removes it.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, because your loop 
`while ($rowf = oci_fetch_array($stidf, OCI_BOTH)) {`
Relies on the data to be returned from the database, when there is no data, the loop will not get executed hence there will be no table to be shown, you can something as follows:

```
$numRows = oci_num_rows($stidf);
if($numRows >0){
   while ($rowf = oci_fetch_array($stidf, OCI_BOTH)) {   ?>          

   <td><?php if ($rowf[0] == NULL) {echo "x";} else { echo $rowf[1];} ?></b></td>
   }
}else{
   <td><b style='color:#FC0000'>There is no Data</b></td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of the `while` will be executed if it the value of `$rowf` is set to true.

> When I get an empty SQL result, all   disappear.

Because `<tr>` `<td>` are the parts of the body of your `while` loop.

> When the SQL result has data, the table, and data presentation work
>   correctly

The value of `$rowf` is set to true and body of the while loop gets executed.